# How to make code indentation display properly in IE8?

Tags: support

I would like to be able to browse this website from work (since I use Mathematica professionally), and due to IT requirements, this means using IE8, which is a little old. For some reason, code sections aren't indented properly when I use IE8 on this site, but they do display properly when browsing StackOverflow.

Has anybody else encountered this, and if so, do you know of a solution?

**EDIT** to add: Of course, now that I'm on my work machine and have Snagit open, the problem completely disappears. :-/

Comment: Please include a screen capture so we can see what you see.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'll do that first thing tomorrow at work.

Comment: I'm far away from my work desktop pc currently but I remember that prior to my upgrade to win 7, the previous installation with IE6 did something similar. It may have to do with safety settings, like allowing JavaScript or so.